# ASP.NET Web API - Thread safe logic for updating an entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have the following method for adding or updating an entity of type `Item` for some User. This method is a part of a Service class a new instance of which is created for each request.

```
public async Task SaveItem(int userId, string name)
{
    var item = await _context.Items.Where(i => i.UserId == userId).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (item == null)
    {
        item = new Item
        {
            UserId = userId,
            Name = name
        };
        _context.Items.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        item.Name = name;
        _context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The problem is that two concurrent requests may create two items for the same user which is not valid. For me it looks like a pretty common piece of code and I wonder what is the default way of dealing with this kind of concurrency issue.

Comment: was originally UserId  not PK and you changed to be PK to ensure it is unique? how did you solve it exactly. I have similar scenario but my UserId  is not PK. another column is PK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to handle `Concurrency Conflicts` properly on your application.

1.Pessimistic Concurrency (Locking)

> If your application does need to prevent accidental data loss in
>   concurrency scenarios, one way to do that is to use database locks.
>   This is called pessimistic concurrency. For example, before you read a
>   row from a database, you request a lock for read-only or for update
>   access. If you lock a row for update access, no other users are
>   allowed to lock the row either for read-only or update access, because
>   they would get a copy of data that's in the process of being changed.
>   If you lock a row for read-only access, others can also lock it for
>   read-only access but not for update.

2.Optimistic Concurrency

> The alternative to pessimistic concurrency is optimistic concurrency.
>   Optimistic concurrency means allowing concurrency conflicts to happen,
>   and then reacting appropriately if they do.

Please read [**Handling Concurrency with the Entity Framework**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) article for more info.

Comment: Thanks, that was a helpful link. I ended up implementing Optimistic handling using try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

If the combination of UserId and Name for an item is supposed to be unique, make it unique in the database.

You could try to solve it with static locking objects... but that will only make it slow and hard to understand/maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two separate functions, one that creates and one that updates.
Or you could try to update, and if it fails, create it, and don't forget to put a unique index in your database.

Answer (score 0):

If the `UserId` field is flagged as **unique** (or identity which is also unique) you are already fine. Whenever you get into that small time gap to add more than one item with the same `UserId` cocurrently, only the first will succeed and all others will fail on adding.